# How to move text labels vertically in tikztiming

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, labels, tikz-timing

In a tikz timing graph I want to reduce the font size of the labels. When I do that they are not vertically centred with the graph anymore. How does one move the label vertically to the center?

The MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=5ex,y=2.2ex},
    x=1ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\rmfamily}]
\small Data   & {[semitransparent]3u} 2D{0} 2D{1}  2D{1} 2D{0} {[semitransparent]2u}\\
\small Clock  & {[semitransparent]3u} LHLHLHLH {[semitransparent]2u}\\ \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I found in the documentation that I can probably use anchor=mid east, but i'm not sure where to put it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, included the wrong picture. I meant veritcally center the label on the left (Data & Clock)

Comment: `\makebox[5ex]{Data}` and `\makebox[5ex]{Clock}` will do it.  You can place `\small` either in or outside of the `\makebox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little `yshift` added to the `timing/name` style. Also, I'd move the `\small` there as well.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=5ex,y=2.2ex},
    x=1ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\rmfamily\small,yshift=2pt}]
Data   & {[semitransparent]3u} 2D{0} 2D{1}  2D{1} 2D{0} {[semitransparent]2u}\\
Clock  & {[semitransparent]3u} LHLHLHLH {[semitransparent]2u}\\ \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm wondering... Did you find that solution in the manual, or do you know of a way (that I don't) to access all `pgfKeys` at `timing/.` or deeper, so you can check, one by one, what they were fed ?

Comment: @marsupilam I assumed that `timing/name` is the style that is used for the nodes that contain the labels/names for each row, so I guess that any TikZ key will work there.

Comment: So *this* was a mere lucky guess on your part ?! I mean the fact the key should be called `name` and not `label` or `title` or `leftWord`...

Comment: @marsupilam Well, given that the `font` key was already used in that style, it's hardly a long stretch to think that other keys would work as well ...

Comment: Right ! Hadn't spotted that.. ! Cheers !

Comment: @marsupilam, TorbjørnT: Indeed, I forgot to describe the style `timing/name` in the manual. It is shown in at least one example there, though. Also, you can indeed use all TikZ keys here, as it is all a tikzpicture internally.

Answer (score 4):

Here, I place the text in equal sized `\makebox`es.  The `\small` can be inside or outside of the `\makebox`, though a slightly different gap will result after the text, depending...

Why the original version of the OP behaves thus, it might be a case of right-aligned labels.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=5ex,y=2.2ex},
    x=1ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\rmfamily}]
\makebox[5ex]{\small Data}   & {[semitransparent]3u} 2D{0} 2D{1}  2D{1} 2D{0} {[semitransparent]2u}\\
\makebox[5ex]{\small Clock}  & {[semitransparent]3u} LHLHLHLH {[semitransparent]2u}\\ \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above MWE fixes the horizontal centering of the two words.  To also fix the vertical alignment, per follow-up comments, one can combine this result with a `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/.style={x=5ex,y=2.2ex},
    x=1ex,
    timing/rowdist=3ex,
    timing/name/.style={font=\rmfamily}]
\raisebox{1.5pt}{\makebox[5ex]{\small Data}}   & {[semitransparent]3u} 2D{0} 2D{1}  2D{1} 2D{0} {[semitransparent]2u}\\
\raisebox{1.5pt}{\makebox[5ex]{\small Clock}}  & {[semitransparent]3u} LHLHLHLH {[semitransparent]2u}\\ \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found that makebox didn't do the trick (because 5ex defines the width). \raisebox did the trick however!

Comment: @Douwe66 I thought you wanted the words centered with respect to each other.  Certainly, a `\raisebox` should accomplish a vertical displacement.  Nonetheless, glad to help.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed a bit ambiguous in my question. 
You brought me in the right direction by using the box environment